# How to make a function of specific arity dynamically?

Tags: python, variadic-functions

I want to do lambda of `n` arguments with `n` being calculated in a run time. The next best solution is:

```
 lambda *x : do_something_with_a_tuple( x )
```

It is almost ok, but I want the exact number to be both checked by the Python itself and seen via func_code. When the `n` is 2, it should work exactly like:

```
 lambda x1, x2 : do_something_with_a_tuple( (x1, x2) )
```

With `n` equals 3:

```
 lambda x1, x2, x3 : do_something_with_a_tuple( (x1, x2, x3) )
```

etc. So I want variadic function to behave like n-adic. Can I do this without eval metaprogramming?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? `x` in your first example is **already** a tuple of that length.

Comment: It's a tuple of _any_ length. I want it to be exactly `n`.

Comment: Can you add an example to help us understand your usecase/scenario?

Comment: I'm making a lisplike s-expression evaluator and s-expressions can have lambdas of specific number of arguments on their own. When I do them over `*x` lambda, I'm loosing control over arity: [link](https://github.com/akalenuk/fakelisp/blob/master/fakelisp.py#L61) It's not that bad, I can do an arity check in run-time, but it would be much better to put it of my hands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can force the definition to take a fixed number of arguments, but you can include a run-time check in the function itself.

```
def make_n_adic(n):
    def x(*x):
        if len(x) != n:
            raise TypeError( "Function takes exactly {0} arguments ({1} given)".format(n, len(x))
        do_something(*x)
    return x
```

Comment: At which point you can just use `lambda x1, x2, x3: ...`; e.g. make the `n` arguments explicit.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Assuming `n` is known at the time you write the code.

Comment: @delnan: *That* is the part I missed. `n` is dynamic. In which case this answer is exactly correct.